# C - fprintf output is not consistent within for loop

Tags: printf

I am printing a vary large dataset to a text file using fprintf:

```
    FILE *ff23=fopen("parts_in_cell_dript_part.txt","wa");
    if (ff23 == NULL)
        error("Error opening text file");
    int N=e->s->nr_parts;
    fprintf (ff23,"%d\n",N);
    for (int k = 0; k < N; k++) {
        struct part *restrict p = &parts[k];
        float xx=p->x[0];
        float yy=p->x[1];
        float zz=p->x[2];
        int id;
        id=p->id;
        fprintf(ff23,"%d %f %f %f %d\n",k+1,xx,yy,zz,id);
   }
   fprintf(ff23,"Finished func\n");
   fclose(ff23);
   exit(1);
```

The output suffers from several problems:

lines overwrite other lines. The first column is should go consecutively from 1 to N.

more/less numbers are printed to the file than expected.
[image]

I have try to use only append but results stay the same.

EDIT:
I tried adding "t" mode, it did not help

Comment: If you're using `fprintf` then the file should be opened in **text** mode - try adding "t" to the mode argument.

Comment: Is it possible that you have multiple processes, or multiple threads within one process, writing to this file at the same time?  Also, "wa" is not a legitimate mode for fopen.  Use either "w" or "a", but not both.

Comment: Problem solved. Indeed I was running on multiple threads and that was the cause for the problem.

Comment: Is it possible to keep using multiple threads and print to text without these stuff happening?

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but you'd have to give us a lot more detail about how the work the threads are doing relates to the content that you want to end up with in the file.  The easiest way to stop the threads from colliding would be to give each thread its own output file (use the thread ID or thread name as part of the filename) but I don't know if that's a sensible approach for the problem your program is trying to solve.